# why did not found the chatgpt event stream data in google chrome devtools

Tags: google-chrome, server-sent-events

I was curious about how chatgpt push message to the client side recently. I have already read some articles that introduce ChatGPT using sse to push message to client side,does chatgpt push answser using server-sent events? if so, why did not seem the event stream data in the conversation request in google chrome?

[image]

by the way, the server-sent events only support get request, why the chatgpt send a post request?

Comment: This only works in chrome when they use the native EventSource implementation

Comment: could you give more info about navtive eventsource, I am using event source in google chrome, what about native event source? @dyingangel666

Comment: I got the same question. I tried MS edge and it cannot display sse as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason EventStreams don't show up in Chrome DevTools is because EventSource is polyfilled.

You can find a discussion about this issue here: [Event does not show up in the Chrome EventStream subtab inside the Network tab when viewing the eventstream connection · Issue #79 · Yaffle/EventSource](https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource/issues/79)

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue from late 2019 on the Chromium Issue tracker for this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1025893

It is still recently commented on and seems to be a pain point for a lot of web developers using Chromium-based browsers.